# How do I debug a nextjs production build?

Tags: debugging, next.js

I have a bug ([this one](https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/1266)) that only happens in production, on the client side.

Next.js by default silences all error messages in production, and turns off all logging client side. This makes it almost impossible to debug what's going on when an error is in production-mode only.

Is there a flag or some other setting that will allow me to debug code built by next.js for production?

Comment: Node errors are logged (at least in vercel), but not, it seems like, React errors :/

Comment: Managed to fix my problem, like described here:   https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/1266#issuecomment-846509060

But still don't know how to debug a production next.js react code base.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, have you found out how to debug Next.js in production?

Comment: @Taha Unfortunately not... :/

Answer (score 2):

As of NextJs 13, you can log errors on client by doing this in `next.config.js`:

```
  // ...
  compiler: {
    removeConsole: false,
  },
  // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm run build && NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' npm run start
```

Comment: does not work in VSC as docs say "To debug server-side Next.js code with Chrome DevTools, you need to pass the --inspect flag to the underlying Node.js process"